# Permissions problem with remote mount

Tags: permissions, mount, sshfs

I am having a simple permissions issue that the solution, or proper setup is eluding me.

I have two servers sitting side by side on the same network.  `.80` is the web server and `.40` is a file server.  I am trying to mount a directory that lies on `.40` onto `.80` and serve as web content (only images).  My mount is successful, and I can navigate the remote directory just fine, as well as add and remove items from it.  But when images viewed in browser, I get **403 Forbidden** or in layman's -- *Permission Denied*

The remote directory on `.40` looks like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 zak zak 4.0K Sep 26 10:36 images
```

The local directory on `.80` looks like this (prior to mount):

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 zak zak 4.0K Sep 26 10:36 images
```

I am using a Private Key to auto mount this directory on boot --

```
sshfs zak@x.x.x.40:/Private/images /var/www/zak_site/images
```

Why am I able to navigate, add and remove from this mount, but I cannot view via http?

**UPDATE**

Apache Error Log:

> [Thu Sep 26 11:29:04.607441 2019] [core:error] [pid 10718] (13)Permission denied: [client 174.31.53.188:58857] AH00035: access to /images/hawks2.png denied (filesystem path '/var/www/zak_site/images') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

---

**note** I will be needing to be able to upload via http as well once I get the permissions straight.  But if I have that issue .. I'll ask a separated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there were **TWO** components that helped solve this.

1)  I set `user_allow_other` in /etc/fuse.conf

However that was not enough .. After reading `-man` I saw the option flag `-o allow_other` on the mount command.  This allows Apache to see and change the files without being a "user" specified in the permissions.

2) So I changed the command to:

```
sshfs -o allow_other zak@10.2.6.40:/Private/images /var/www/zak_site/images
```

All is well with Apache displaying my images now.